# Reorder stacked barplot x based on fill values with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

A survey with 5 questions is administered. The questions share the same set of possible answers. Here are the data, reshaped for plotting with ggplot2.

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

data <- data.frame(ID = c(1:500),
                   q1  = factor(sample(c(1:4), 500, replace = T),
                                labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                   q2  = factor(sample(c(1:4), 500, replace = T),
                                labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                   q3  = factor(sample(c(1:4), 500, replace = T),
                                labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                   q4  = factor(sample(c(1:4), 500, replace = T),
                                labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")),
                   q5  = factor(sample(c(1:4), 500, replace = T),
                                labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))) %>%
gather(question, value, q1:q5)
```

I want to sort the ordering of the questions based on number of a given response. So instead of this...

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = question , fill = value)) +
  geom_bar() + 

  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  scale_fill_manual("Value", values = c("#2171B5", "#6BAED6", "#BDD7E7", 
                                   "#EFF3FF"))
```

[image]

...I want the order of the questions along the x axis to be based on the count of answer = D, for example.

Comment: I would recommend 1) precomputing the quantity in advance; 2) reordering via setting `scale_x_manual`.

Answer (score 7):

Got it. Ordered by the number of responses = A, in the example below.

```
  data$question <- reorder(dataf$question, data$value, function(x) max(table(x)[1]))  

   ggplot(heatDf, aes(x = question, fill = value)) +
      geom_bar() + 
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
      scale_fill_manual("", values = c("#2171B5", "#6BAED6", "#BDD7E7", 
                                       "#EFF3FF", "grey30"))
```

[image]

Comment: you can also do `ggplot(data, aes(x = factor(question, levels=as.character(count(data, question, value) %>% ungroup %>% filter(value=="D") %>% arrange(n) %>% .$question), ordered=TRUE)
 , fill = value))` but it's usually way better to do this outside ggplot like you did here.