# Ordering stacked barplots based on a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe, geom-bar

Example of data(daten), see below:

```
               bundesland gender freq percent_freq label_hight labels
4       Baden-Württemberg      w  125    71.428571    35.71429 71.4 %
5       Baden-Württemberg      m   43    24.571429    83.71429 24.6 %
6       Baden-Württemberg   k.A.    7     4.000000    98.00000    4 %
7                  Bayern      w  122    68.156425    34.07821 68.2 %
8                  Bayern      m   43    24.022346    80.16760   24 %
9                  Bayern   k.A.   14     7.821229    96.08939  7.8 %
10                 Berlin      w   41    63.076923    31.53846 63.1 %
11                 Berlin      m   22    33.846154    80.00000 33.8 %
12                 Berlin   k.A.    2     3.076923    98.46154  3.1 %
```

I use this data to plot a stacked barplot.

```
p <- ggplot(daten, aes(x=bundesland, y=percent_freq, fill=gender)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +                           # contour colour
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +             # reverse legend
  geom_text(aes(y=label_hight, label=labels))+          # add the labels
  theme_hc() +
  scale_fill_tableau() +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0 )), 
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0 )), 
         linetype = guide_legend()) + theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Now I'd like to have the plot ordered after percent_freq where gender = w. I'm aware of [Reorder stacked barplot x based on fill values with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234856/reorder-stacked-barplot-x-based-on-fill-values-with-ggplot2), so I tried:

```
daten$bundesland <- reorder(daten$bundesland, data$gender, function(x) max(table()[1]))
```

But I get:

```
Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  Argumente müssen dieselbe Länge haben
```

(Arguments must have same length)

What am I doing wrong? Or is there an even better approach to do this?

Data:

```
structure(list(bundesland = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("", "Baden-Württemberg", "Bayern", 
"Berlin", "Brandenburg", "Bremen", "Hamburg/", "Hessen", "Mecklenburg-Vorpommern", 
"Niedersachsen", "Nordrhein-Westfalen", "Rheinland-Pfalz", "Saarland", 
"Sachsen", "Sachsen-Anhalt", "Schleswig-Holstein", "Thüringen"
), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("w", "m", "k.A."), class = "factor"), 
    freq = c(125L, 43L, 7L, 122L, 43L, 14L, 41L, 22L, 2L, 109L
    ), percent_freq = c(71.4285714285714, 24.5714285714286, 4, 
    68.1564245810056, 24.0223463687151, 7.82122905027933, 63.0769230769231, 
    33.8461538461538, 3.07692307692308, 81.3432835820896), label_hight = c(35.7142857142857, 
    83.7142857142857, 98, 34.0782122905028, 80.1675977653631, 
    96.0893854748603, 31.5384615384615, 80, 98.4615384615385, 
    40.6716417910448), labels = structure(c(6L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 
    9L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 15L), .Label = c("10.8 %", "8.1 %", "81.1 %", 
    "24.6 %", "4 %", "71.4 %", "24 %", "68.2 %", "7.8 %", "3.1 %", 
    "33.8 %", "63.1 %", "13.4 %", "5.2 %", "81.3 %", "11.1 %", 
    "77.8 %", "18.2 %", "81.8 %", "1.1 %", "15.9 %", "83 %", 
    "33.3 %", "66.7 %", "11.6 %", "23.3 %", "65.1 %", "27.3 %", 
    "6.5 %", "66.2 %", "3 %", "69.7 %", "14.3 %", "52.4 %", "16.1 %", 
    "72.8 %", "14.5 %", "7.2 %", "78.3 %", "16.2 %", "21.2 %", 
    "62.6 %", "10.7 %", "16.7 %", "72.6 %"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("bundesland", 
"gender", "freq", "percent_freq", "label_hight", "labels"), row.names = 4:13, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you post the data in an easy to read format e.g. the output of `dput(daten)`

Comment: Thanks, I just did it. Is this okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to subset the data to only the females prior to reordering.

```
female <- subset(daten, gender == "w")
female$bundesland <- reorder(female$bundesland, female$percent_freq)
daten$bundesland <- factor(daten$bundesland, levels = levels(female$bundesland))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! You solved a problem in a few minutes, that I didn't solve in a week.